# Crear un ciclo con 12 posibles resultados tomando la fecha de la computadora como el detonador

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trato de crear un ciclo en python el cual con la libreria import time tomo el mes actual que se tiene en el equipo por lo cual este decidira cual sera el escenario que se ejecute de 12 posibles cada uno correspondiente al mes del año, lo e creado con ciclos if pero quisiera una idea de optimiciarlo con algun otro ciclo siempre que cambien el mes cambie el escenario. El codigo es el siguiente:

```
import time

mes = int(time.strftime("%m"))
print (mes)

if (mes==1):
    print("El mes es enero")
elif (mes==2):
    print("El mes es febrero")
elif (mes==3):
    print("El mes es marzo")
elif (mes==4):
    print("El mes es abril")
elif (mes==5):
    print("El mes es mayo")
elif (mes==6):
    print("El mes es junio")
elif (mes==7):
    print("El mes es julio")
elif (mes==8):
    print("El mes es agosto")
elif (mes==9):
    print("El mes es septiembre")
elif (mes==10):
    print("El mes es octubre")
elif (mes==11):
    print("El mes es noviembre")
elif (mes==12):
    print("El mes es diciembre")
```

Comment: `if` no es un ciclo. No veo ciclos en tu código.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No entiendo muy bien a qué te refieres con "el escenario", pero supongo que quieres decir que ejecute un código diferente según cuál sea el mes, y que lo de imprimir el nombre del mes es solo un ejemplo que has puesto, pero que el código real debería hacer otras cosas además de imprimir el mes (y que serían cosas diferentes para cada mes).

Una posibilidad es tener una función separada para cada posible caso, algo así:

```py
def caso_enero():
  print("Ejecutando escenario para enero")

def caso_febrero():
  print("Ejecutando escenario para febrero")

def caso_marzo():
  print("Ejecutando escenario para marzo")

def caso_abril():
  print("Ejecutando escenario para abril")

def caso_mayo():
  print("Ejecutando escenario para mayo")

def caso_junio():
   print("Ejecutando escenario para junio")

def caso_julio():
   print("Ejecutando escenario para julio")

def caso_agosto():
   print("Ejecutando escenario para agosto")

def caso_septiembre():
   print("Ejecutando escenario para septiembre")

def caso_octubre():
   print("Ejecutando escenario para octubre")

def caso_noviembre():
   print("Ejecutando escenario para noviembre")

def caso_diciembre():
   print("Ejecutando escenario para diciembre")
```

Una vez hayas definido el código de cada escenario en una función separada, tu programa principal podría contener una lista con esas funciones, y elegir qué función ejecutar por su índice de la lista (que sería el número del mes menos 1):

```py
import time

escenarios = [caso_enero, caso_febrero, caso_marzo, caso_abril, caso_mayo,
  caso_junio, caso_julio, caso_agosto, caso_septiembre, caso_octubre,
  caso_noviembre, caso_diciembre]

# Seleccionar escenario a ejecutar
mes = int(time.strftime("%m"))
escenario = escenarios[mes-1]

# Y ejecutarlo
escenario()
```

Comment: Gracias abulafia esta es la respuesta que necesita lamento no haber sido mas claro pero entendiste mi idea lo que requeria

Answer (score 0):

Python trabaja con listas, que se indexan a partir de cero.

Lo usual es tener una lista de meses:

```
meses = ["enero", "febrero", "marzo", "abril", "mayo", "junio", "julio", "agosto", "septiembre", "octubre", "noviembre", "diciembre"]
```

y luego:

```
mes = int(time.strftime("%m"))
print(mes, meses[mes - 1])
```

El `mes` va de 1 en adelante, pero la lista `meses` se indexa de cero; por eso le resto uno al menos para usarlo de indice.

produce

```
8 agosto

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

También podemos usar diccionarios, donde las claves sean el número del mes y como valor podemos asignarle una función.

Si solo vamos ha hacer una operación sencilla, como lo es imprimir, podemos usar una función lambda.

```py
meses = {1: lambda: print("El mes es enero"), 2: lambda: print("El mes es Febrero"), 8: lambda: print("El mes es Agosto")}
mes = int(time.strftime("%m"))

meses[mes]()
#o
#escenario = meses[mes]
#escenario()
```

Si por el contrario vas a hacer varías cosas más podemos optar por lo que hizo @abulafia en su respuesta, definir cada función aparte.

```py
def caso_enero():
  print("Ejecutando escenario para enero")

def caso_febrero():
  print("Ejecutando escenario para febrero")

def caso_agosto():
   print("Ejecutando escenario para agosto")

meses = {1: caso_enero, 2: caso_febrero, 8:caso_agosto}
mes = int(time.strftime("%m"))

meses[mes]()
#o
#escenario = meses[mes]
#escenario()
```

Comment: Overkill. Basta una simple lista.

Comment: Solo dejo aquí otra adopción, que sea conveniente una lista antes que esto, pues sip.